# Does Antalya have business-friendly facilities like a copy center, cheap and quiet Internet access centers?

Tags: internet, business-travel, antalya

I'm probably flying out to Antalya tonight, and I'm all out of actual business cards.

So I need to do a quick businesscard print on arrival, as soon as I get updated templates on my mail.

Is there a copy centre/mini lab available to print my .jpgs on Saturday? Or, at least, an cybercafé-type place with a color printer capable of two-side printing?

Comment: Just a tip, when I needed that I went to a photo studio, I brought my own paper, I give them the jpg and they printed it for me. It was not business cards, and it was not in antalya, but keep this in mind it might be what you end up doing.

Comment: @kagali-san - did you find anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

[There is at least one online company in Antalya](http://www.printbusinesscards.com/cities/Turkey/Ordering-Antalya-Business-Cards.php) that promises delivery within 24 hours, and you can pay extra for earlier delivery.  So it's entirely possible that they could take your design and print them for you within hours if you let them know in advance.